# Boost exceptions lead to stack pointer corruption (Run-Time Check Failure #0 ...)

Tags: c++, exception, boost, stack-pointer

In an small project i am using several boost packages (asio, property_tree, filesystem, etc.) and i had to notice, that everything works fine, until an exception gets thrown somewhere in the boost packages. It happens in all those packages, but i was now able to boil it down to the following minimal program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "boost/throw_exception.hpp"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  boost::throw_exception(std::exception("foo")); // <-- this will produce the problem

  throw std::exception("foo"); // <-- this works as expected

  return 0;
}
```

The exception is thrown fine, but when the program terminates i get

```
Run-Time Check Failure #0 - The value of ESP was not properly 
saved across a function call ...
```

I tried to debug this (i am using boost 1.49.0 in visual studio 2010 express with crt statically linked) but the problem appears when all visible code is already executed. I can see that the std:exception destructor wen't through, but after that ("in" the return statement of my program) the message box is triggered.

EDIT:
Some additional infos:

- In the minimal program above, boost is only used headers only
- No other lib-files are involved
- Only ntdll.dll and kernel32.dll are loaded by the program
- No additional threads are beeing created
- The problem also appears, when i link dynamically against CRT

EDIT2:
Again more infos:

- added includes in the program above
- the problem appears too, when i throw a runtime_error instead
- the problem vanishes when i catch the exception with (...) or (std::exception)
- the problem even remains cured, when i rethrow the exception

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using the dynamic runtime, so that both Boost and your program use the same one? If you are linking statically to the runtime, then you might have two runtimes loaded into the process, which is can cause problems. The last time I saw that problem though, it was caused by having different calling conventions between a program and a DLL (e.g. cdecl/fastcall/pascal). Just using a static runtime shouldn't make a difference though.

BTW: There is a simple test that you can make to find out where the error is. If you include the according code from Boost into your program, you effectively get an in-place compiled, statically linked Boost. If that works, then you can be reasonably sure that the problem is the way that you build or link things.

Comment: "If you are linking statically to the runtime, then you might have two runtimes loaded into the process" - how comes? Does OP write he links Boost dynamically?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i added some statements to my question to clarify.

Comment: I tried now with dynamic CRT, the problem still exists. Any further Ideas?

Comment: Oh. I didn't even think of the possibility that you're using a header-only part of Boost, which of course rules out any linker-related issues. There are three more things that come to mind: 1. What if you actually catch the exception? 2. The standard doesn't have a ctor for `std::exception` taking a char*, that is an MS extension. What if you replace this with `std::runtime_error` instead? 3. Which #includes do you have?

Comment: Tried your suggestions (thanks!) and added results in my question. By catching the exception, the problem is solved for me. Still the question remains open, since i cant explain what the problem actually is.

Comment: I've been reading a bit what boost::throw_exception actually does, and that seems to depend on BOOST_EXCEPTION_DISABLE. What I would try next is to reduce the issue to a minimal example by copying the content of boost/throw_exception.hpp into your sourcefile and then deleting lines until you have nothing left to remove. My guesses are between a compiler error and some undefined behaviour in Boost's code. Good luck!

Comment: Ok, finally i had some more time to work on this topic, it seems that the whole problem is caused by the declaration of boosts throw_exception function with BOOST_ATTRIBUTE_NORETURN, which results in a __declspec(noreturn) for MSVC. If i remove this from my own copy of the function, the problem is solved. Not shure however what i should now do about it, maybe i should post it as a potential bug in the boost bug database.